# SAS EG asking for credentials "randomly" when called from VB

Tags: vba, sas, enterprise-guide

I have the following function in an `Excel` sheet module, which sends `SQL` queries to `SAS`:

```
Function run_query(query)

Dim app         ' application
Dim project     ' Project object
Dim sasProgram  ' Code object (SAS program)
Set app = CreateObject("SASEGObjectModel.Application.5.1")
Set project = app.New
Set sasProgram = project.CodeCollection.Add
sasProgram.Text = "PROC SQL;" + query + " QUIT;"
sasProgram.Run
app.Quit

End Function
```

It sometimes works like a charm, and most often doesn't, as it asks for my credentials (triggered by command `sasProgram.Run` as it's where the debugger stops), I didn't find a way to make the error, or success, reproducible.

I've set my `credentials persistence` to `Persist for user` but I still have issues.

I've also tried to set my `Autentification` to `None (attempt anonymous connection)` and `Windows integrated (Uses your current windows account)` and none of them changed the situation.

Comment: relevant: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/SAS-EG-Batch-Failing-Ideas-for-De-Bugging/td-p/234742 and http://support.sas.com/kb/30/917.html